# Producer messages using Apache.NMS Console app and Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, amqp, activemq-artemis, apache-nms

I am trying to produce messages to and consume messages from ActiveMQ Artemis queues for the first time. I am able to connect and produce messages via Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ as well as Apache.NMS.AMQP when I use the code in a C# console application. However, when I put that same code in a C# Windows forms application the `CreateSession` method call runs forever.

```
IConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory(brokerUri);
using (IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection(username, password))
{
    using (ISession session = connection.CreateSession(AcknowledgementMode.AutoAcknowledge))
    {
        IDestination destination = session.GetQueue(queueName);
        IMessageProducer producer = session.CreateProducer(destination);
        IMessage textMessage = session.CreateTextMessage(text);
        producer.Send(textMessage);
    }
}
```

My broker is using SSL, and I use the Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ library with the `brokerUri="ssl://mybroker:443"` and I use Apache.NMS.AMQP with the `brokerUri="amqps://mybroker:443"`. Again, each of these work fine when run in a Console app, but not a Windows Forms app.

Comment: Which version of ActiveMQ are you using?

Comment: Do both the Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ and Apache.NMS.AMQP clients fail in the same way when running in a Windows Forms app?

Comment: How do you know that `CreateSession` is running forever? Are you using a debugger? If so, can you descend into `CreateSession` to see exactly what's taking so long?

Comment: Versions...AMQ version 7.8.7.CR1-redhat-00001, Artemis: 2.16.0.redhat-00046; if that is what you are asking. and yes, they both "fail" at the same CreateSession method. I brought the code in through nuget. when i F11 at the CreateSession method it just runs; doesn't enter the code.

Comment: This sounds like an environmental problem. Have you tried setting up a packet capture to see if anything is transmitted from the client to the broker? If nothing is transmitted then this is 100% a client-side problem. If something is being transmitted to the broker and the client is waiting for a response then that would indicate a problem with the broker or maybe a network issue of some kind.

Comment: I am having the same problem with 2.0 libs of Amq.  The same code works fine with 1.8.0 lib version. So there is a problem with 2.0 version and win forms app

Comment: Thanks for that find, Adrya. I was able to get Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ v1.8 to work in a GUI but not Apache.NMS.AMQP v1.8. 

In the end i dont plan on using a GUI so i should be able to use the 2.0 versions, but i like to unit test my libraries with GUIs. If anyone has any additional insight please chime in, however.

Comment: I would encourage you guys to report any issues on the [ActiveMQ users mailing list](https://activemq.apache.org/contact) otherwise the problem may never actually get fixed.

Comment: Thank you Justin, a bug was created for this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQNET-818 to be followed up :)

Comment: Thanks for submitting that bug, Adrya. The workaround discussed in that email thread (wrapping the ActiveMQ code within "System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>{...)}; works for me in the 2.0 versions.

Answer (score 0):

For the tl;dr crowd:

We've encountered this issue in AMQ6 and AMQ7.  The workaround mentioned in the jira issues and the comments above is to wrap any AMQ connection code in a Task.Run, like so:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>{
    connnection.Start();
});
```